# Apache RewriteMap and hiding the URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to implement persistent URLs under Apache and I'm having trouble getting the URL passed back from the RewriteMap to remain hidden. That is, if I have the PURL:

http://www.mysite.com/psearch?purl=12345

and the mapped value for it is:

http://www.mysite.com/search?name=test&type=test2

I want the PURL to be the URL displayed in the browser address bar. Unfortunately, it keeps displaying the site that the PURL maps to instead. My rule is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /psearch(/)*$
RewriteMap mapper prg:/scripts/rewritetest.pl
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ${mapper:$1} [L]
```

All the mapper does right now is return a URL for a test page on the system, since I'm trying to get the address hiding working. And I know I'm not grabbing the parameters right now, I'm just trying to get the test running using the psearch keywork, and will add the rest later if it's possible to hide the address.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of the output of RewriteLog in your question. Set RewriteLogLevel to 5.

Comment: The leading slash here looks wrong: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ${mapper:$1} [L]`  Try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${mapper:$1} [L]`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that I was returning the full URL, which forced a full redirect.  Passing back just the REQUEST_URI portion made things work.

Forcing the headers to expire also helped, since things were getting cached that were obscuring when something was working properly.