# Replacing Rewrited urls from DB fields in PHP

Tags: php, url-rewriting

My environment is Apache, DB is mySQL and language is PHP.

What I need is to create a middle layer which intercept the request and check the urls such as `"http://www.something.com/apple/ipad-2-cases/"` and then look up the db and where both `apple` and `ipad-2-cases` has a counter such as below:

**Products Table**

1. p_id --> *1*
2. p_name --> *"iPad"*
3. p_custom_url --> *"ipad-2-cases"*

**Brands Table**

1. b_id --> *2*
2. b_name --> *"Apple"*
3. b_custom_url --> *"apple"*

and convert the url into `"http://www.something.com/products.php?b_id=2&p_id=1"` from where I can grab `b_id` and `p_id` to bring out appropriate product info.

It basically quite looks like the way implemented in `Joomla`. You can define your own user-friendly url by typing an extra field otherwise it implements default setting anyway.

Since I am new to PHP, I don't quite know how to accomplish this. IN asp.net I've been using URL-Writer library which uses `HttpHandlers` and `HttpModules` to intercept the current request and make proper replacements.

Is there any library or something out there which can help me out on this one? Or do I need to use `.htaccess` (I know I need to turn on the `mod_urlwrite` on `.htaccess`)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `RewriteMap` may be your friend here - see e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717796/apache-rewritemap-and-hiding-the-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ids, use names.

Using mod_rewrite in .htaccess go from

```
http://www.something.com/apple/ipad-2-cases/
```

to

```
http://www.something.com/products.php?b=apple&p=ipad-2-cases
```

and find the relevant ids inside products.php

**EDIT**
In .htaccess create a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([A-Za-z_-]+)/([A-Za-z_-]+)$ products.php?b=$1&p=$2
```

Comment: Names might not be unique and that cause a problem for me but seems a good idea, still it is not the answer tho ;)

Comment: And also I am talking thousand products here and writing all of these takes quite a time and parsing .htaccess for such a product mass could take time and cause slow response time.

Comment: No, just create a rule in .htaccess. Check my answer now. As for the uniqueness - you will have to ensure this.